# Does destructor is end-point of program?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

Assumption I have `~MyClass()`

```
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
private:
    map<int,string> m_colNameMap;

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}
```

As I known that `m_colNameMap` will be automatic free memory, but I wonder that after go out of destructor, does all memory was release to OS? or the release process act behind the `}`?

If I put a mem check point like this :

```
_CrtMemState crtMemState;
_CrtMemState s1;
_CrtMemState s2
MyClass(){
 _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s1);

}
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
  _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s2);

    if (_CrtMemDifference(&crtMemState, &s1, &s2)) {
    _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&crtMemState);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
   }
}
```

Is this correct way?

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this destruction sequence reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Destruction_sequence).

Comment: The destructor of `MyClass` will call the destructor of all of the members - so if you **manually** allocate memory anywhere, you need to explicitly release it in the destructor body, but if you only use memory owned by well-designed classes (e.g. the Standard Library containers) then you are fine.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point of this question but I think it's obvious that "free" of memory for members has to happen at/just after the `}` of the destructor. The members are valid inside the destructor so it can't happen before. And c++ has no "garbage collection" that can free memory "long time" after so it has to happen at/just after the `}`

Comment: Assuming `map` and `string` are `std::map` and `std::string`, destroying a `MyClass` will release all memory used by the map and the strings it contains. It is up to the implementation of the standard library whether or not that memory is also released to the operating system or - in your case - in a way that can be detected by system-dependent code that checks memory usage. Practically, C++ libraries often do NOT release memory to the OS until the program terminates, since making requests to the OS every allocation and deallocation is inefficient

Answer (score 0):

You're associating "the" destructor with the end of the program. However, a destructor is associated with the end of an object. And your program typically has many objects. Some are short-lived, some are long-lived.

That si why your idea of checking for memory differences generally makes no sense.